# STM32CUBEIDE stuck in Reset_Handler when attempting to debug

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I'm having some trouble debugging my STM32.

Since last weekend, I had to rebuild my Ubuntu 19.10 workstation from scratch, so all of my tools are newly installed and at whatever the latest version is (as far as I can tell). Everything was working fine before the rebuild.

I'm running STM32CUBEIDE with the following version details:

```
Version: 1.3.0
Build: 5720_20200220_1053 (UTC)
```

Whenever I attempt to flash and debug the microcontroller, the bits are uploaded and verified correctly, but the μc gets stuck inside of the Reset_Handler, defined inside of `Startup/startup_stm32l412c8tx.s`.

This happens even with a newly generated sample project. I have not physically changed the breadboard I'm programming in any way from when it was working.

I'm using the STLINK-V2 USB programmer over SWD.

I can pause, step and play from the debugger, but execution is trapped inside the Reset_Handler loop.

I can manually reset the device (with the momentary switch) and the state changes are reflected in the debugger as follows:

```
[256.299] Device_GetStatus():  ST-LINK device status: RESET_MODE
[256.572] Device_GetStatus():  ST-LINK device status: RUN_MOD
If I tail the debugger output log, I see the following (repeating eternally unless paused):
[14.655] write():  <12> Tx: $60000020006800400068004000800000000000000000000000000000f09f00200d05000800000000000000000000000000000000f09f00204b3900081602000800000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f09f002000000000#e6
[14.656] read():  <12> Rx: $qXfer:threads:read::0,bfb#fb
[14.656] write():  <12> Tx: $l<?xml version="1.0"?><threads><thread id="1" core="0" name="main"></thread></threads>#8b
[14.656] read():  <12> Rx: $z1,8000216,1#95
[14.657] write():  <12> Tx: $OK#9a
[14.657] read():  <12> Rx: $m800050d,1#5b
[14.657] handlePacket():  Reading 0x1 bytes of memory from addr 0x800050d 
[14.658] write():  <12> Tx: $f8#9e
[15.083] read():  <12> Rx: $qXfer:threads:read::0,bfb#fb
[15.083] write():  <12> Tx: $l<?xml version="1.0"?><threads><thread id="1" core="0" name="main"></thread></threads>#8b
[15.083] read():  <12> Rx: $qXfer:threads:read::0,bfb#fb
[15.083] write():  <12> Tx: $l<?xml version="1.0"?><threads><thread id="1" core="0" name="main"></thread></threads>#8b
```

This is where the debugger points inside Startup/startup_stm32l412c8tx.s

```
.equ  BootRAM,        0xF1E0F85F
    .section    .text.Reset_Handler
    .weak   Reset_Handler
    .type   Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:
  ldr   sp, =_estack    /* <-- DEBUGGER HERE */
```

I'm hopeful that there's some simple setting or software version that I've lost or missed.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the launch configuration for debug? - under "Startup" tab there are "Runtime Options" does the start address match your linker settings?

Comment: Thanks for checking in on this. I wound up abandoning the STM Cube IDE and using arm-none-eabi and Makefiles instead. Life has dramatically improved ever since!